# Is there any way to save the Microsoft Teams tab SSO Azure AD access token into I-Frame cookies using MSAL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, msal.js

I am using MS Teams SDK for getting Tab-SSO Access Token. Is there any way to store this Access Token in I-Frame Cookies like MSAL cache user Authentication information after a successful sign-in?. If it works then it is possible to load any web application into Teams-App Tab under the same Tenant without separate Authentication, the loading application takes the cached Access Token for Authentication. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The tokens are bound to the Azure AD application, not the web application itself, so you certainly should be able to reuse them in your 2nd app. You'd need to register a new redirect location in the Azure AD app, but that's easy enough to do. There's no need then for cookies, because you can simply request the token from the Teams context any time you need it - it's handling the caching, and the token retrieval, for you.

Comment: @Gopal Prakash-Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Hilton Gisenow - I got the Token from Teams context but how to use this Token to Authenticate the second Web App. Whenever I load the Second App in the Teams Tab it's showing a CORS Domain error because the Second app redirects the user to the AD sign-in page.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing a 'CORS' error. Are you able to send a screenshot?